# Lauricella integral transformation?

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

The Lauricella hypergeometric function $F_D$ has two different integral representations I know of. First one can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series#Integral_representation_of_FD):

> $$\scriptsize F_D^{(n)} (a,b_1,\dots,b_n,c;x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}(1-x_1t)^{-b_1}\cdots(1-x_nt)^{-b_n}~dt,\qquad \operatorname*{Re}(c)>\operatorname*{Re}(a)>0$$

And second one can be found in eq. $(1.9)$ of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1240435361):

> $$\small \frac{\Gamma(\beta_1)\cdots \Gamma(\beta_n)\Gamma(\gamma-\beta_1-\cdots-\beta_n)}{\Gamma(\gamma)}F_D(\alpha,\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_n,\gamma,x,\cdots,x_n)$$
>   $$\small =\mathop{\int\cdots\int}_{z_1,\cdots, z_n\geq 0\\\\ 1-z_1-\cdots-z_n\geq 0} z_1^{\beta_1-1}\cdots z_n^{\beta_n-1}(1-z_1-\cdots -z_n)^{\gamma-\beta_1-\cdots-\beta_n-1}\times (1-x_1 z_1 -\cdots -x_n z_n)^{-\alpha} dz_1\cdots dz_n$$

Since both definitions should be equivalent, there must be a transformation one could apply to the first integral to get the second and vice versa. Unfortunately, I could not guess what transformation that is. Does anyone knowledgeable see it and can tell me how to transform one integral into the other? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I have been looking at this recently and think I know the way into it if your willing to put up with an old man's backtracking over and over :) Basically Lucy Slater's "Generalized HyperGeometric Functions" section 8.2 for Appell F_1() provides what I consider to be templates for progress.  The first formula is reasonably easy (it's Slater's second).  The second formula is more interesting.  Slater does start a process.  But it's algebraic and would be recursive.   I will give a personal view, slightly different, in the next comment.

Comment: Since the second formula is basically over a n-dimensional tetrahedron, I would think that recursively defining (n-1) dimensional slicing would provide an evaluation of x,y coefficients.  If the coefficients, one by one, are equal then you have a implicit transform.  To me a good alternative is to treat both as conformal maps on the complex plane; they "look" like that.  That would be neat since conformal maps are invertable; but my grasp is of how is very low.  Interesting though.

Comment: @rrogers please see my answer I just posted below.

Comment: Your last equation sprawls into a sidebar on my computer.  Could you, or would you mind if I inserted a CRLF?

Comment: @rrogers Thanks for pointing this out! I split the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to demonstrate the equivalence of the two integral representations (3.24) and (3.25) of the hypergeometric function of type $(n+1,m+1)$ in  [Aomoto and Kita](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-4-431-53938-4) (of which the Lauricella function is a special case (2,m+1)).

We start with the definition of the hypergeometric series of type $(n+1,m+1)$ as given in eq. (3.5) of [Aomoto and Kita](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-4-431-53938-4):
\begin{align}
\label{Fdef}{\tag{1}}
F(\alpha_i,\beta_j,\gamma,x)=\sum_{\nu_{ij}=0}^\infty\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(\alpha_i)_{\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\nu_{ij}}\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}(\beta_j)_{\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_{ij}}}{(\gamma)_{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\nu_{ij}}\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\nu_{ij}!}\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}x_{ij}^{\nu_{ij}},
\end{align}
where the infinite sum is over all dummy indices $\nu_{ij}$ with $i=1,2,...,n$ and $j=1,2,...,m-n-1$. Here $(x)_y$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

We will also require an integral identity given in eq. (3.17-3.19) of [Aomoto and Kita](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-4-431-53938-4):
\begin{align}
\label{id1}\tag{2}
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(\alpha_i)_{\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\nu_{ij}}}{(\gamma)_{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\nu_{ij}}}&=c_1\int_{{u_1>0,..,u_n>0}\atop{1-\sum_{i=1}^nu_i>0}}\prod_{i=1}^ndu_i\,u_i^{\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\nu_{ij}+\alpha_i-1}\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\right)^{\gamma-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{i}-1},\\
c_1&=\frac{\Gamma(\gamma)}{\Gamma(\gamma-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i)\prod_{i=1}^n\Gamma(\alpha_i)},
\end{align}
or alternatively, simply replacing labels and names of dummy indices, we can also write the same integral identity as:
\begin{align}
\label{id2}\tag{3}
\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}(\beta_j)_{\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_{ij}}}{(\gamma)_{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\nu_{ij}}}&=c_2\int_{{u_1>0,..,u_n>0}\atop{1-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}u_j>0}}\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}du_j\,u_j^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\nu_{ij}+\beta_j-1}\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}u_i\right)^{\gamma-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\beta_j-1},\\
c_2&=\frac{\Gamma(\gamma)}{\Gamma(\gamma-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\beta_j)\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\Gamma(\beta_j)},
\end{align}
Now we can plug $(\ref{id1})$ into $(\ref{Fdef})$ and observe:
\begin{align}
F(\alpha_i,\beta_j,\gamma,x)=&c_1\int_{{u_1>0,..,u_n>0}\atop{1-\sum_{i=1}^nu_i>0}}\prod_{i=1}^ndu_i\,u_i^{\alpha_i-1}\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\right)^{\gamma-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{i}-1}\\
&\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\sum_{\nu_{ij}=0}^\infty(\beta_j)_{\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_{ij}}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{(u_ix_{ij})^{\nu_{ij}}}{\nu_{ij}!},\\
=&c_1\int_{{u_1>0,..,u_n>0}\atop{1-\sum_{i=1}^nu_i>0}}\prod_{i=1}^ndu_i\,u_i^{\alpha_i-1}\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\right)^{\gamma-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{i}-1}\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^nu_ix_{ij}\right)^{-\beta_j},\notag
\end{align}
where in the last step we have recognized multinomial expansions and resummed them. This gives us the first integral representation (3.24) in [Aomoto and Kita](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-4-431-53938-4).

Similarly, we can instead plug (\ref{id2}) into (\ref{Fdef}) and analogously observe:
\begin{align}
F(\alpha_i,\beta_j,\gamma,x)=&c_2\int_{{u_1>0,..,u_n>0}\atop{1-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}u_j>0}}\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}du_j\,u_j^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\nu_{ij}+\beta_j-1}\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}u_i\right)^{\gamma-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\beta_j-1}\\
&\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{\nu_{ij}=0}^\infty(\alpha_i)_{\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\nu_{ij}}\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\frac{(u_jx_{ij})^{\nu_{ij}}}{\nu_{ij}!},\\
=&c_2\int_{{u_1>0,..,u_n>0}\atop{1-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}u_j>0}}\prod_{j=1}^{m-n-1}du_j\,u_j^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\nu_{ij}+\beta_j-1}\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}u_i\right)^{\gamma-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}\beta_j-1}\\
&\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^{m-n-1}u_ix_{ij}\right)^{-\alpha_i}.\notag
\end{align}
Here we have again recognized and resummed multinomial expansions. This gives us the dual integral representation (3.25) in [Aomoto and Kita](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-4-431-53938-4).

With this the equivalence of the two dual representations is demonstrated.

Comment: @rrogers For instance in (1) the very first summation $\sum_{\nu_{i,j}=0}^\infty$ is just a shorthand notation for $\sum_{\nu_{1,1}=0}^\infty...\sum_{\nu_{n,1}=0}^\infty...\sum_{\nu_{1,m-n-1}=0}^\infty...\sum_{\nu_{n,m-n-1}=0}^\infty$. Basically, all sums over $\nu_{i,j}$ where either $i$ or $j$ or both were not defined before implies summation over labels for all $i,j$. In cases where it was defined before, it is unambiguous.

Comment: Sorry I erased my comment. Let me repeat part: is $$\nu^{ij}$$, a function or a set?  i.e. is it an array of numbers or "an array of dummy indices"?  I don't have Aomoto and Kita but am trying to read your result.  I still don't see the mapping between the line (one-dimensional) integral and the tetrahedron/solid integral.  Aside from the fact they yield the same power series in x,y after being integrated.  I thought that was what you asked for.

Comment: BTW: do you have a reference for the negative _multinomial_ expansion; similiar to the binomial one?  I looked around and, while it's very reasonable, I couldn't actually find a reference.

Comment: All the $\nu_{ij}$ are literally just labels for summation, we could have called all of them just $a,b,c,d,...$ etc. For multinomial expansion, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem . One can write pochhammer symbols in terms of gamma functions and see that here we have a direct generalization of the integer case discussed in the above link. The sum representation is the defining representation of a hypergeometric function. By showing that two integral representations reduce to the same sum representation we prove that they are equivalent.

Comment: The $\nu^{i,j}$ in $x_{ij}^{\nu_{i,j}}$ looks like a scalar power?  I was looking for validation for the expansion $1/(x_{1]+x_{2}...x_{n})^\alpha $ but I can work it out for myself.

Comment: @rrogers That's right, it is a scalar power, just like the $k_t$ in the first equation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem